# cant show pivot result

Tags: sql-server, pivot

i got **error** in pivoting result like below :

```
select tanggal,[1],[2] from
(
SELECT
    (CONVERT(DATE, tanggal, 103)) as tanggal,
        id_jenis,
     (harga * jumlah) as total
FROM
    [dbo].[PNL_TP_SISA_PRODUKSI]
WHERE
    YEAR (CONVERT(DATE, tanggal)) = 2016
AND MONTH (CONVERT(DATE, tanggal)) = 8
AND id_unit_pengolah = 40) 
c
PIVOT (MAX(total) FOR id_jenis IN([1],[2]))
```

and this errors show :

> [Err] 42000 - [SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ')'.

kindly confuse because of this **error**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to provide alias name for `pivot`

```
 select tanggal,[1],[2] from
    (
    SELECT
        (CONVERT(DATE, tanggal, 103)) as tanggal,
            id_jenis,
         (harga * jumlah) as total
    FROM
        [dbo].[PNL_TP_SISA_PRODUKSI]
    WHERE
        YEAR (CONVERT(DATE, tanggal)) = 2016
    AND MONTH (CONVERT(DATE, tanggal)) = 8
    AND id_unit_pengolah = 40) 
    c
    PIVOT (MAX(total) FOR id_jenis IN([1],[2])) as pvt
```